# Select statement setting DateTime precision

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to set the precision of my DateTime in my SQL select statement. I am unable to do this before getting to the query. I am using SQL Server 2008.

The current format is:

```
2012-05-14 14:54:45.307
```

I want to keep to drop the milliseconds and seconds from the DateTime giving me:

```
2012-05-14 14:54
```

I am unsure if this can be done i really hope so, thank you.

Comment: Are you doing this for presentation purposes or are you trying to run a particular WHERE clause (e.g. find me all the data from this particular minute)? Your comment to one of the answers below has me confused. Also note that if your column is DATETIME, then the value you specify above is not "the current format" - it is not a string, it is stored internally as two integers, the above format is just how Management Studio is showing it to you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is simpler than the other options (no string conversions or date math):

```
SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, GETDATE());
```

If you still need it to be an explicit DATETIME (e.g. if your application will barf on a minor type change), you can just wrap it in another convert:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, GETDATE()));
```

This will still have minute granularity but will be a proper DATETIME type with zeroes for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove them:

```
update tablename
set datecolumn = DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, datecolumn), datecolumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't and keep the DateTime casting.  However, if you want it formatted for display (VARCHAR), you can use CONVERT like this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),GETDATE(),120)
```

Comment: So it is not possible to say do Select * from Table with a where and remove the time there?

Comment: You can do it from something other than SQL after you have the recordset, but if you're just using management studio as your application layer, then you're looking at a formatting fix in your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), 1, 16)
```

Or to avoid declaring a VARCHAR without a length:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(), 120), 1, 16)
```

Comment: Please don't specify `VARCHAR` without length. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: "Madhivanan, this is certainly okay if he is converting dates and integers (unless you know of dates or integers that will be > 30 characters)?  He wasn't suggesting that what he's doing is a good idea, but compared to other ways this "feature" is abused, I think his exception is relatively safe." - @AaronBertrand

Comment: I did not know about the 30 character limit when doing this, thanks for the heads up.  I agree that it is bad practice to declare variables or table columns in this way and have not used it as such, and though it works with integers and dates I'll try to steer away from it there as well.  Good advice, good comments on your blog as well